# Is Crystal Reports XI R2 compatible with SQL Server 2016?

Tags: .net, crystal-reports, sql-server-2016, crystal-reports-xi

I need to check whether Crystal Reports XI R2 is compatible with SQL Server 2016. Right now this report works fine in SQL Server 2012.

Appreciate your valuable feedback.

Thanks.

Comment: I've not found any official statement about supported SQL Server versions for CR XI R2, but can say that i've worked many times with this combination and have not seen any problem so far.

Comment: @MatSnow : Thanks for your information. Hope there will not be any issues. Will try to test once.